# Dictionary list from a for loop with if else hasattr

Tags: python, list, dictionary

following code to start:

```
products = [{
  "id": x.id,
  "fabric": x.fabric.name,
  "fabricimg": x.fabric.fabric_cover.url,
  } for x in entry_obj.all()]

cart_data = {
  "products": products,
  "total": cart_obj.total
}

return JsonResponse(cart_data)
```

This works fine for creating my list products with the dictionaries from the `x(objects)` in `entry_obj.all()`.
But now I have the scenario that I have some `x(objects)` with no `x.fabric.name`, and instead will have to use a filler for example a simple string like `"noname"`.

How can I use an if statement in the existing for loop to catch the case of name not existing and instead setting the key fabric to my string value?

I thought of using:

```
if hasattr(entry_obj,"name") > "fabric": x.fabric.name
else > "fabric": "noname"
```

But I'm unsure where to put it in the for loop plus how to iterate through the `x(objects)` in `entry_obj` for that matter so I can still give `Json` the right `cart_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) with the 3rd *default* argument:

```
products = [{'id': x.id, 'fabric': getattr(x.fabric, 'name', 'noname'),
             'fabricimg': x.fabric.fabric_cover.url} for x in entry_obj.all()]
```